# WP8 - Unable to update Tile Parameters

Tags: windows-phone-8, tile

Basically everything was going fine until i clicked my app's secondary tile and nothing had been updated. What i'm currently working on right now is a note app and one of the main functionality is pinning the note to the start screen.

**The problem is that once the tile gets created it's assigned a unique random ID so that if the content of the tile needs changing that id will be used to find that tile IF it's pinned and update so. The Unique ID is generated once the user clicks save on a new note and will not change.**

**Basically It does that part all right it's just that once i click the secondary app it takes me to a page with the parameters which i initially created with not the ones i modified.**

e.g.
I create a note and the TITLE: Hello and MESSAGE: HI!!!. and pin it to the start. Now the tile shows me the title and message.
I decide to make changes to the note. I change the title to: yes and message to: no. i open up the app and make the changes to the note and everything gets updated. Now i have the modified note which is automatically updated. Now the tile shows me the modified note. so the tiles content will be yes and no.

But i decide to view the note by clicking the tile. It takes me to the page but instead of showing the modified content of the note, it shows me the initial note text which is Hello and Hi!! rather than Yes and No.

My Sourcecode for the creating and updating is:

```
 Dim contextMenuListItem As ListBoxItem = DirectCast(ItemsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(DirectCast(sender, MenuItem).DataContext), ListBoxItem)
    Dim item As SampleData1 = DirectCast(contextMenuListItem.Content, SampleData1)
    Dim TileToFind As ShellTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("parameter2=" & item.ID))
    If TileToFind Is Nothing Then
        Dim TileData As New IconicTileData() With { _
           .Title = item.Name, _
           .WideContent1 = item.Name, _
           .WideContent2 = item.Description, _
            .WideContent3 = item.ID, _
           .SmallIconImage = New Uri("Assets/Tiles/IconicTileSmall.png", UriKind.Relative), _
           .IconImage = New Uri("Assets/Tiles/IconicTileMediumLarge.png", UriKind.Relative), _
           .BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent}
        ShellTile.Create(New Uri("/CreateNote.xaml?parameter=" & TileData.Title.ToString & "&parameter1=" & TileData.WideContent2.ToString & "&parameter2=" & TileData.WideContent3.ToString, UriKind.Relative), TileData, True)

    Else
        Dim TileData As New IconicTileData() With { _
           .Title = item.Name, _
           .WideContent1 = item.Name, _
           .WideContent2 = item.Description, _
           .SmallIconImage = New Uri("Assets/Tiles/IconicTileSmall.png", UriKind.Relative), _
           .IconImage = New Uri("Assets/Tiles/IconicTileAssets/IconicTileMediumLarge.png", UriKind.Relative), _
           .BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent}

        TileToFind.Update(TileData)

    End If
```

VIDEO showing what i mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsedPk7YKdw

**ADDED** =================================================================================

Code which creates the tile with the navigation parameters:

```
ShellTile.Create(New Uri("/CreateNote.xaml?parameter=" & TileData.Title.ToString & "&parameter1=" & TileData.WideContent2.ToString & "&parameter2=" & TileData.WideContent3.ToString, UriKind.Relative), TileData, True)
```

On the CreateNote Page the parameters:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)

    Dim parameter As String = String.Empty
    Dim parameter1 As String = String.Empty
    Dim parameter2 As String = String.Empty

    If NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parameter", parameter) Then
        Me.Title.Text = parameter
        OldFName.Text = parameter
    End If
    If NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parameter1", parameter1) Then
        Me.Message.Text = parameter1
    End If
    If NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parameter2", parameter2) Then
        Me.IDG.Text = parameter2
    End If

End Sub
```

Do you see my problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have updated notes data in the data source besides updating Tiles data? I assumed when a tile tapped, CreateNote page opened and load note data from data source based on Uri parameters.

Comment: Hi, yea the Note does get updated and saves into a storage location. Once the note is saved that triggers the update tile event. So basically its all updated and when the user clicks the tile with the updated information, the navigation goes to the page but shows the old contents. I've updated my post with a video clearly showing what i mean.

Comment: The more relevant code to include in the question is the one which read Uri parameters and load relevant data in CreateNote page. The problem is more likely to be there, since creating and updating Tile data has worked as you want.

Comment: Are you able to help me with this? :)

Comment: We need more information, especially about the code that pull data from data source based on the Uri parameter passed.

Comment: I did update my post. I added the piece of code which retrieves the parameters on the CreateNote page where it shows the data and also added the code which creates the tile navigation. Is there anything i need to add? let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem :

> Your application will display information passed to Uri parameters, but in the update Tile operation **you leave the Tile Uri not updated with new parameter values** -only Tile's data being updated-.

And possible solution :

> Since NavigationUri property of ShellTile is read-only, I assume that updating Tile's Uri is not supported. Therefore I suggest an alternative to always create a new Tile, then remove old Tile if it already exist.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that post at least now i get the picture :)